# Streaming data from Postgres to a REST API

Tags: postgresql, rest, streaming

I want to write a small utility application which will connect to a Postgres table and stream the data from it to a REST API endpoint.

I don't care what language this utility application is written in, but it needs to be streaming because the amount of data in the Postgres table won't fit in memory.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Cursors. For real-time updates, `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`. Or if you want to get fancy, logical decoding.

Comment: If you want data from PG, why don't you just page it?.. `LIMIT OFFSET`

Comment: https://www.pipelinedb.com/ seems like a tool that does this out of the box. Tools like [Hasura](https://hasura.io), [postgrest](https://postgrest.com/en/v0.4/) provide the API tooling out of the box. I'm not sure about streaming support though. We're looking at adding streaming support within a few weeks for Hasura. Discalimer: I work at Hasura.